# biblatex: Remove location field in bibliography if empty

Tags: biblatex, authoryear

In biblatex, I would like to remove the location (aka address) field in the bibliography for `@manual` entries that lack a location (address). Otherwise an unsightly pair of empty brackets is the result. An MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}


\usepackage[
backend=biber, 
defernumbers=true, 
style=numeric, 
bibstyle=authoryear,
autocite = superscript,
date=year, 
giveninits=true, 
sorting=none,
]
{biblatex}

% Changes for Book
\csletcs{abx@macro@publisher+location+date@orig}{abx@macro@publisher+location+date}
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
    \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date@orig}}
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1\printunit{\addspace}}


\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}

@manual{Wilke:2020aa,
    author = {Claus O. Wilke},
    date-added = {2023-11-26 13:10:50 -0800},
    date-modified = {2023-11-26 15:12:25 -0800},
    note = {R package version 1.1.1},
    title = {cowplot: Streamlined Plot Theme and Plot Annotations for 'ggplot2'},
    url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=cowplot},
    year = {2020},
    bdsk-url-1 = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=cowplot},
    }
    
@manual{R-Core-Team:2023aa,
    address = {Vienna, Austria},
    author = {{R Core Team}},
    date-added = {2023-11-18 21:11:58 -0800},
    date-modified = {2023-11-18 21:16:30 -0800},
    organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
    title = {\textsf{R}: A language and environment for statistical computing},
    url = {https://www.R-project.org/},
    year = {2023},
    bdsk-url-1 = {https://www.R-project.org/},
    }
    
\end{filecontents}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}


I would like to remove the empty address field for the Wilke citation, but not the R Core Team citation \autocite{Wilke:2020aa, R-Core-Team:2023aa}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

With the following output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}

\usepackage[
backend=biber, 
defernumbers=true, 
style=numeric, 
bibstyle=authoryear,
autocite=superscript,
date=year, 
giveninits=true, 
sorting=none,
]{biblatex}

% Default global settings for publisher+location+date
\csletcs{abx@macro@publisher+location+date@orig}{abx@macro@publisher+location+date}
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
    \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date@orig}}
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1\printunit{\addspace}}

% Customizing @manual bibliography driver
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{manual}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iflistundef{location}
    {\printlist{}}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printlist{location}%
       \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
       \printfield{year}}%
    }
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@manual{Wilke:2020aa,
    author = {Claus O. Wilke},
    note = {R package version 1.1.1},
    title = {cowplot: Streamlined Plot Theme and Plot Annotations for 'ggplot2'},
    url = {https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=cowplot},
    year = {2020},
}

@manual{R-Core-Team:2023aa,
    address = {Vienna, Austria},
    author = {{R Core Team}},
    organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
    title = {\textsf{R}: A language and environment for statistical computing},
    url = {https://www.R-project.org/},
    year = {2023},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

I would like to remove the empty address field for the Wilke citation, but not the R Core Team citation \autocite{Wilke:2020aa, R-Core-Team:2023aa}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Uses `\iflistundef{location}` to check whether the location list is defined for a `@manual` entry.
If it is, the location and year are printed within parentheses; otherwise, nothing is printed in place of the location.

With the following output:
[image]

Comment: Incredible! I would never have come up with this by myself. Thank you so much, @John Smith